# unable to send SMS on android using code I wrote

Tags: java, android, sms

I am trying To build my first application which will send ans SMS message.
everything looks OK:
1. SMS application opens
2. The URI is inserted
3. Text message is typed

Only the last bit of pressing the "SEND" button is not performed.

I am using the code demonstrated [here on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=paAjAEOsh2w):

which includes this AndroidManifest.XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="il.ac.ruppin.reco.www.sendsmsyoutube">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SENR_RESPONSE_VIA_MESSAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and this MainActivity.java

```
package il.ac.ruppin.reco.www.sendsmsyoutube;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:+972528524520");
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO,uri);
        intent.putExtra("sms_body","Message from my new application");
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct URI format for SMS is `sms:` (and **not** `smsto:`)

```
String number = "+972528524520"
Uri uri = Uri.parse("sms:" + number);

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
intent.putExtra("sms_body", "Message from my new application");
startActivity(intent);
```

This starts the default activity for sending an SMS message.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but somehow this produced the same behavior. the message is ready to send but not actually sent.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with the SmsManager Class

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, sms, null, null)
```

where,
phoneNo = send To , sms = your message to be passed

Comment: I saw and tried the SmsManager sollution but looking at my logs I see "Sending SMS message: uid 10171 does not have android.permission.SEND_SMS" although I have a line in my AndroidManifest saying "    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>"

Comment: Update:

Now on wards as we have restricted permission for SMS then you might need to check the document [Here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview) to make sure you are not breaking the Privacy Policy.

Answer (score 0):

Ok according to Hardik Vegad answer I used the SmsManager.
What I had to do is to allow the application to send sms.
Setting>apps>MyAp>permissions

Thanks for your help

Comment: Yeah, And I suggest you to prefer runtime permission for these kind of operations that will be the best practice. Happy Coding.